# the size of nice tree decomposition

Tags: trees, satisfiability, big-o-notation

Recently, I am reading paper [An Upper Bound for Resolution Size: Characterization of Tractable SAT Instances](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-53925-6_28), which use tree decomposition to give an upper bound for SAT resolution refutation.

For a given nice tree decomposition $T=(V(T),G(T))$.

**My question:** Why $O(3^{treewidth})*V(T)$ is still $O(3^{treewidth})$

my question comes from the process of proving Theorem 3 from Lemma 2
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the claim that $O(3^{tw}) \cdot |V(T)| = O(3^{tw})$, as you mention.

Instead, $O^*(3^{tw}) \cdot |V(T)| = O^*(3^{tw})$. The notation $O^*$ is a shorthand used to suppress polynomial factors in the input size $n$. You should read $O^*(3^{tw})$ as $O(3^{tw} \cdot \text{poly}(n))$.